# Angularjs : How to display data after update on my UI

Tags: angularjs

I have angular project  My Requirement is : How to display data after update on my UI without refreshing, Data store in server i want it to display on Contact and Recent Tab immediately after Updating.

UI Bindings:

```
 <li class="media contact-card">
       <div class="media-left">
          <a ui-sref=".viewClient({'clientId':client._id})">
          <img class="media-object img-circle" src="https://placehold.it/42x42" alt="https://placehold.it/64x64">
          <!--<div class="circle" ng-class="getRandomColorClass('Xipesh Gandhi')"><p>{{generateInitialChar('Dipesh Gandhi')}}</p></div>-->
        </a>
      </div>
       <div class="media-body">
        <div class="pull-left">
        <h4 class="media-heading pull-left">{{client.firstName}} {{client.lastName}}</h4>
        </div>
       <div class="pull-right">
        <a class="" ui-sref=".editClient({'clientId':client._id})"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" ></i></a>
        <a class=""> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" ></i></a>
      </div>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
         <span>{{client.address}}</span>
         <span>{{client.birthDate | date:'mediumDate'}}</span>
     </div>
 </li>
```

View :

```
     <div class="tab-wrapper">
                <tabset justified="true">
                    <tab heading="CONTACTS">
                        <div class="tab-content">
                            <div>
                                <div class="pull-right">
                                    <a class="add-client-link" ui-sref=".client"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" ></i> Add Contact </a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="hr"></div>

                            <div class="scrollable-container">
                                <ul class="media-list">
                                    <contact-card data-client="client" ng-repeat="client in clientList"></contact-card>
                                </ul>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </tab>
                    <tab heading="RECENT">
                        <div class="tab-content">
                            <div>
                                <div class="pull-right">
                                    <a class="add-client-link" ui-sref=".client"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" ></i> Create Meeting </a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="hr"></div>

                            <div class="scrollable-container">
                                <ul class="media-list">
                                    <contact-card data-client="client" ng-repeat="client in clientList"></contact-card>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </tab>
                </tabset>
            </div>
```

Controller:

```
      $scope.updateClientList = function(client, operation){
        if(operations.ADD === operation){
            //$scope.clientList.push({firstname: $scope.client.firstName, lastname: $scope.client.lastName});
            //$scope.clientList.push(client);
            $scope.clientList.push (client);
           // $scope.clientList = [];

        } else if(operations.EDIT === operation){

        } else if(operations.DELETE === operation){

        }
        $state.go('meeting-home.viewClient', {'clientId':client._id});
    };
```

Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: This is very hard to answer without a Plunker or JSFiddle. Usually, if your data is bound to the scope, it should automatically update when you change it.

Comment: what does this do? `$scope.clientList.push (client);
            $scope.clientList = [];` you push a client and again make the list empty?

Comment: my data has store on server and display on form-view immediately after updating, but it is not display without refreshing in CONTACT and RECENT tab.

Comment: Nilesh i forgot to put it in comments :  $scope.clientList = [];

Comment: Can you show the UI bindings?

Comment: Why are you doing ` $scope.clientList = [];` after ` $scope.clientList.push (client);` ? And instead of `$scope.clientList = [];`, you should use `$scope.clientList.splice(0,$scope.clientList.length)];`

Comment: Hi Aniket it I forgot to put in comment : $scope.clientList = [];,

Comment: Hey Nilesh i have added UI binding..Plz  give some suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Please comment $scope.clientList = []; in your code. it will work. Any how you are not mentioning UI binding details.